# How to modify an array in javascript file

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do an automation in a file.js with the following structure:

```
** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["change this string and save the file.js",
    ],
};
```

This is a tailwind framework configuration file, I need to enter the content array and add elements and save the file.js.

I'm trying to create a script that reads this file.js and modifies the array mentioned above.

Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: _"I'm trying to create a script that..."_ - If you have any problems with an actual implementation we're happy to help -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a new file that contains the content, and import that file in this file.js? The file where you import from is then just a module.exports = [ array ] (then at least you can write the file to import from scratch, instead of modifying an existing file with potentially other content in it :) )